# How to get all bills for a given class name from Quickbooks desktop using SDK?

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I am using c# console application to retrieve data from QB desktop edition and I would like to know if it is possible to get all bill/expense entries for a given class name. All the expense line items have the class name specified in it. I need to get the information by class name. I tried to use the "BillQuery" from the below mentioned OSR but i am not sure how to specify the class name in the billquery. Can anyone provide your suggestions?

https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the QuickBooks OSR:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

The `BillQuery` request supports filtering `Bills` by these criteria:

- TxnID (query by TxnID)
- RefNumber (query by the Bill # / Reference # field)
- ModifiedDateRangeFilter (query by the date the bill was last modified)
- TxnDateRangeFilter (query by the date of the bill)
- EntityFilter (query by the vendor the bill belongs to)
- AccountFilter (query by the A/P account the bill is in)
- RefNumberFilter (query by the Bill # / Reference # field)
- CurrencyFilter (query by the currency)
- PaidStatus (query by whether or not the bill has been paid)

Don't see a filter for `Class` in that list? *Then QuickBooks does not support filtering by `Class`.*

If you want to filter by `Class`, you'll have to query for *all* bills, and then do the filtering in your code yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Is it possible to get the details from the report through SDK. There is  a report called Profit and Loss by Class in Quickbooks and is it possible to get the details from this report through SDK?

Comment: Look at `GeneralSummaryReportQuery` in the OSR. Should be possible.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it and let you know if i face any issues.